# DBgrid column very wide

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi-xe, dbgrid

We have the following case. We need to change a field in a SQL Server database from varchar to nvarchar. After the change, all the dbgrid shows the very wide column. How can we globally adjust the size of this column?

Column `Lastname` is very wide:

[image]

Comment: By using the field name or column index of the dbgrid.

Comment: You changed the datatype but you didn't fix the data. You will want to do an RTRIM on your column(s) to remove the trailing spaces that were added when the column was fixed width.

Comment: @SeanLange Even he do so, if let's say the col is nvarchar(50) , the dbgrid col width will be long even the column has only few chars.

Comment: @Sami not sure what you mean. Those columns will display wide because there are spaces in there causing the data to remain wide.

Comment: @SeanLange We are not sure if he has spaces

Comment: @SeanLange It's the size as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO PATIENT VALUES
('Patient1'),
('Patient2'),
('Patient3');
```

Now let's see the `DBGrid` how to show the data:

[image]

Your problem is the `Sise` of your column (50) here

[image]

You can change the `DBGrid` column `Width` as:

```
DBGrid1.Columns[1].Width := Value;
```

also, be sure that `dgColumnResize` option of the `DBGrid` is enabled (true), in that way you resize the column as needed at runtime.

Comment: I needed to do this programatically, since my DBGrid data is populated also programatically after the form is created. Life saver! Thanks